# Finding the slopes of the sides of a triangle, when only given the slopes of internal angle bisectors

Tags: analytic-geometry

Finding the slopes of internal or external angle bisectors, when given the slopes of the sides of a triangle, it's a simple question, the one you can easily find in any textbook of analytic geometry.

But  the reverse problem : finding the slopes of the sides of a triangle, when only given the slopes of internal angle bisectors. Is it possible? Is there a straightforward formula for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The slopes of the internal bisectors intersect at the incentre I. You will thus know the angles AIB, BIC and CIA.

180 = AIB + IAB + IBA

180 = ACB + 2*IAB + 2*IBA

ACB = 2*AIB - 180

From this you can figure out the side slopes.

Comment: Could you explain how? For instance, if m and m' are the slopes of BI and CI, I know that   tan(BIC)= -|(m'-m)/1+m'm| because BIC is obtuse, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: If you know the slopes of the equations of the angle bisectors, I know that it's fairly easy to find the angles of the triangle, but finding the slopes of the equations of the sides remains puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Paul Childs, finally the solution dawned on me!

First step: Knowing the slopes of the bisectors you calculate tan(A/2), tan(B/2), tan(C/2).

Second step: you calculate the slopes of straight lines from the vertices making these angles to the bisectors.

Case closed.